# Can't hide out of screen elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's the link to a little site I'm builiding for a friend, http://yveschaput.com/gdf2
I managed to get the animation I wanted, meaning sliding divs according menu choices.
My problem is the target divs are out of canvas (outside screen boundaries) and the screen jumps to those outside divs when you clik on a link of the menu.

I'm not sure I'm explaining this properly but if you test the link I provided, you'll see exactly what I mean.

Right now, I'm using a class "invisible"(visibility: hidden;) on those divs. I tried to use "display: hidden;", which kinda solve my out of screen problem, but you can't animate a hidden element.

I am using Bootstrap 3, that could be my problem as I don't really use much of Bootstrap' functions. I just used their template COVER as a basis and maybe part of Bootstrap functionalities are getting in the way?
Or am I so out of the basics of CSS and HTML?

Anyways, any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

EDITED: I tried to copy my code to fiddler.js, http://jsfiddle.net/34As5/
It look like crap but you will see the effect of the move out of the screen.

Here's how my HTML is setup:

```
<div class="site-wrapper">

      <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

        <div class="masthead clearfix">
            <div class="inner">
                <h3 class="masthead-brand">&nbsp;</h3>
            </div>
          </div>

        <div class="cover-container">
            <div class="menuContainer">
                <div id="menu" class="inner cover">
                    <h1 class="cover-heading title"><img src="img/TheStromWithin.png"></h1>
                    <ul class="text-left menu">
                        <li class="info">
                            <a href="#info" class="">Info
                                <p class="pull-right">.01</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="preview">
                            <a href="#preview" class="">Preview
                                <p class="pull-right">.02</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="buy">
                            <a href="#buy" class="">Buy
                                <p class="pull-right">.03</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="cover-footer text-center tradewinds">
                        <p class="">NEW ALBUM RELEASE</p>
                    </div>
                  </div> <!-- /#menu -->
            </div> <!-- /menuContainer -->

            <div class="itemContainer">
                <div id="info" class="inner cover invisible">
                    <h1 class="cover-heading"><img src="img/info.png"></h1>
                    <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo.</p>
                    <div class="cover-footer text-center tradewinds">
                        <p class="back"><a href="#menu" >BACK</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /#info -->

                <div id="preview" class="inner cover invisible">
                    <h1 class="cover-heading"><img src="img/preview.png"></h1>
                    <div class="lead">
                        <audio preload="auto" controls>
                            <source src="audio/Guy Duggan Fournier - GuySongs - 00 - The Voice Within_01.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
                            <source src="audio/Guy Duggan Fournier - GuySongs - 00 - The Voice Within.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
                            <!-- <a href="audio/Guy Duggan Fournier - GuySongs - 00 - The Voice Within.mp3">Sample</a> -->
                        </audio>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cover-footer text-center tradewinds">
                        <p class="back"><a href="#menu" >BACK</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /#preview -->

                <div id="buy" class="inner cover invisible">
                    <h1 class="cover-heading"><img src="img/buy.png"></h1>
                    <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo.</p>
                    <div class="cover-footer text-center tradewinds">
                        <p class="back"><a href="#menu" >BACK</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /#buy -->
            </div><!-- /itemContainer -->   
            <div class="mastfoot rocksalt">
                <div class="inner">
                    <p><img class="logo" src="img/logo2.png"> &copy; 2014 <a href="http://yveschaput.com">yveschaput.com</a> - <a href="#">Credits</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /cover-container -->

    </div><!-- /site-wrapper-inner -->

    </div><!-- /site-wrapper -->
```

Comment: Share your code instead of a link to your website.

Comment: I have added my HTML and a link to fiddler.js

Comment: would start by containing page to viewport to get rid of horizantal scroll bar `body{ width:100%; overflow:hidden}`

Comment: I left the overflow on so I could scroll back and see if the animation was happening, otherwise I had to refresh and not see anything. Thought the body was at 100% though. An oversight.

Comment: Have you tried preventing the default behavior of the links so they don't scroll the page to the position of the target element? Something like `$('#menu a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});`

Comment: Dang! I would've never thought of this one. That's what happened when you don't code for a while. Thanks Koala_dev. I just tested it out in fiddler and it seems to do the trick. I'll try it out tonite when I get home on my actual dev site. Thanks again.